# 100% Width is not working as the background image of Div

Tags: html, css

I have an image Which i need to show as background image with 100% width in footer of my webpage.But my image is getting cut at the right of the footer.

Here is my code in HTML..

```
<div id="footer" class="footer-shadow">
</div>
```

And here is the css.

```
.footer-shadow
{
position:relative;
background-image: url('../img/new_images/footer-bg.png');
margin-top:2px;
height: 220px;
width: 100%;
color: gray;
}
```

Please help me to correct it and make it responsive to suit all web page size .Thanks .

Comment: You've set the width of `.footer-shadow` to `100%`. Not the `background-image`, try the `background-size` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simple this:

```
background: url('../img/new_images/footer-bg.png') center center no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
```

Comment: Or background-size:cover, maybe better for responsive design?

Comment: It depend on user which would he like. If he want 100% width, this will do it whether image is any size.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use background-size:

```
.footer-shadow
{
position:relative;
background-image: url('../img/new_images/footer-bg.png');
margin-top:2px;
height: 220px;
width: 100%; /* it sets the div width */
color: gray;
background-size: cover; /* now bg image is full width */
}
```